# Even dimensional indecomposable simply-connected closed manifolds with a free action of $\mathbb{Z}/4$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

Proposition 2.29 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology asserts that $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is the only nontrivial group that can act freely on even dimensional spheres.

My question: Which even dimensional indecomposable simply-connected closed manifolds admit a free action of $\mathbb{Z}/4$?

Note that the only simply-connected closed 2-manifold is the 2-sphere, but in dimensions four and higher there are simply-connected, closed manifolds which are not homotopy equivalent to an $n$-sphere.

Of course, $\mathbb{Z}/4$ acts freely on odd dimensional spheres, so it also acts freely on the product of an odd dimensional sphere and another odd dimensional simply-connected closed manifold. Do you have more nontrivial examples?

Thank you!

Comment: The disjoint union of four spheres will admit such a group action.

Comment: five-holed torus. Actually, a normal torus. Or $S^1\times M$

Comment: @HagenvonEizen The four-pronged fidget-spinner. Of course!

Comment: $S^3 \times S^3$ will work; any cyclic group acts freely on either factor. More generally, $S^3$ times any odd-dimensional simply connected closed manifold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case you aren't happy with fiber bundles (as they are, perhaps, "too close" to being decomposable), here's a whole infinite family of simply connected $4$-manifolds which are not fiber bundles and which admit a free $\mathbb{Z}_4$ action.

(Note that $4$ is the minimal dimension where you can find such an example since a simply connected $2$-manifold is automatically $S^2$).

To that end, let $M = S^2\times S^2$ and let $\phi:M\rightarrow M$ with $\phi(x,y) = (-y,x)$ be the order $4$ fixed point free homeomorphism in Jyrki's answer.  Let $n,s\in S^2$ denote the north and south poles.

Pick $N$ to be any simply connected $4$ manifold which is not homeomorphic to $S^4$. Note that this implies the second Betti number $b_2(N)\geq 1$.  Connect sum 4 copies of $N$ to $M$ at each of the points $(n,n), (n,s), (s,n),$ and $(s,s)$.  Call the resulting $4$-manifold $N'$.

Notice that $\phi$ extends to an order $4$ fixed point free homeomoprhism of $N'$ by permuting around the copies of $N\setminus\{Ball\}$.

Now, there are compact $4$-manifolds with arbitrarily large second Betti number.  For example, one can take connect sum of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ with itself any number of times.  Since $b_2(N') = 4b_2(N) + 2 \geq 6$, which follows, for example, from Meyer-Vietoris, we have an infinite family of $N'$ up to homotopy.

Finally, why are none of the $N'$ bundles?  Well, if it's a bundle of the form $S^1\rightarrow N'\rightarrow B^3$, then the long exact sequence (LES) in homotopy groups, together with the fact that $\pi_1(N')$ is trivial implies $\pi_1(B^3)$ is trivial.  Hence, $B^3$ is a sphere (Poincare' conjecture), so $\pi_2(B^3)$ is trivial.  Then the LES  again tells us $\pi_2(N') = 0$.  This contradicts the fact that $b_2(N') \geq 6$.

What if it's a bundle of the form $F^2\rightarrow N' \rightarrow B^2$?  Well, as above, we must have $\pi_1(B^2) = 0$, so $B^2 = S^2$.  Since $\pi_2(F^2)$ is either $\mathbb{Z}$ or trivial, this shows $\pi_2(N')$ is generated by at most $2$ elements.  So, $b_2(N') \leq 2$, a contradiciton.

Finally, if it's a bundle $F^3\rightarrow N'\rightarrow S^1$, then the LES shows that $F^3$ has infinitely many components.  This contradicts the fact that $N'$ is compact.

Comment: Nice, glad you did the work here.

Comment: Towards the end it was a bit technical for me (grad school topology is 30 years in my past), but I think I got the idea. Sort of :-). IMHO this should be the accepted answer. Unless Mike tops it, that is!

Comment: @Jyrki:  Well, I'm not picky what the OP decided about the accepted answer.  And this answer came into being because of your example - I knew that $S^2\times S^2$ had a free $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ action, but I learned from you that it has a free $\mathbb{Z}_4$ action.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am not looking to compete. I don't really know what the OP wants, anyway.

Comment: @Mike Understood. Shooting at a moving target may become annoying.

Comment: Permuting components together with taking antipodes of them gives the group of signed permutations $C_2\wr S_n$ acting on the $n$-fold cartesian power of any sphere. But, some signed permutations have fixed points - the unsigned permutations obviously do! I don't know what would be the biggest subgroups giving rise to a free action?

Comment: @Jyrki:  I also don't know the biggest subgroups giving a free action.  An obvious lower bound is a $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ which acts as $-1$ on the first coordinate and uses a shift (modulo $n$) on the factors.

Comment: @Jyrki:  In fact, it seems that a subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_{2 g(n)}$ can occur where $g(n)$ is the Landau function:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function

Comment: Well spotted, Jason. I think that we can also get the quaternion group $Q_8$ acting freely on the fourth cartesian power. Generators corresponding to $i$ and $j$ would be $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto (-x_2,x_1,-x_4,x_3)$ and
$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto (-x_3,x_4,x_1,-x_2)$ unless my maps went the wrong way. Fixed-point-free groups were classified by Zassenhaus (1930s?), and there aren't too many in general (and subgroups of $C_2\wr S_n$ in particular).

Answer (score 3):

Proffering $S^3\times S^3$ as an example.

We can identify $S^3$ with $SU(2)$, i.e. complex matrices of the form
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr}z_1&z_2\\-\overline{z_2}&\overline{z_1}\end{array}\right),
$$
where we add the constraint $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1$. These can, in turn, be identified with unit quaternions. Anyway the diagonal matrix $D=diag(i,-i)$ is obviously of order four, and multiplication by it gives a free action of $C_4$ on $S^3$.

We then let it act diagonally on $S^3\times S^3$.

Observe that $\pi_1(S^3)$ is trivial, so the same holds for $S^3\times S^3$ as well.

---

As a 4-dimensional example I suggest $S^2\times S^2$. Taking advantage of the antipodal mapping $\overline{x}\mapsto-\overline{x}$ we can construct a fixed-point-free homeomorphism of order four $\phi$ by the recipe
$$
\phi(\overline{x},\overline{y})=(\overline{y},-\overline{x}).
$$
The composition square $\phi\circ\phi$ simply maps both components to their antipodes, so it cannot have fixed points. Therefore neither do the first or the third powers (a fixed point of either would also be a fixed point for the square). Again, the space is also simply connected.

---

Qiaochu Yuan observed that $SU(3)$ is an example that is not a product of lower dimensional spaces. It is a [fiber bundle over $S^5$ with fibers $S^3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#The_group_SU(3)) though. I'm too ignorant to tell whether we can also construct lower dimensional examples as fiber bundles. It's been a while, and I never built up a large enough personal collection of example manifolds to refer to in the first place :-(

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example which is not a product?

Comment: @Zheyan: $SU(3)$. Can you make up your mind what question you actually want to ask? What do you want to know?

Comment: The reason all odd-dimensional spheres have a $\Bbb Z/4$ action is because they really have a circle action. This observation gives you a $\Bbb Z/4$ action on all lens spaces. If you want things that aren't fiber bundles, take a Seifert fibered space all of whose exceptional fibers have stabilizer coprime to $4$; for instance, the Brieskorn sphere $\Sigma(3,5,7)$.

Comment: I didn't notice the simple connectedness assumptions. So we just want closed manifolds with fundamental group $\Bbb Z/4$. In dimension 3 there is only the lens space. I think it is clear that this is way too broad in higher dimensions, though.

Comment: (eg take any such 4-manifold and start connect summing with random simply connected 4-manifolds.)

Comment: @Mike:  We think eerily alike ;-)  You comment was 17 seconds before my answer!